# scroll menu doesnt recognize ends fiddle Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm making this scrollable menu,

**PROBLEM**

It doesnt recognize the ends (left & right). I added an script bellow but it works for the scroll event....I think the problem is recognizing the `.animate()` event since the movement is given with the arrows (they animate `.scrollmenu`)

```js
$("#left").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   $(".scrollmenu").animate({ "left": "+=60px" }, "slow" );
});

$("#right").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   $(".scrollmenu").animate({ "left": "-=60px" }, "slow" );
});
 
  
///detect ends 
 $(function () {
        var scrollLeftPrev = 0;
        $('.scrollmenu').scroll(function () {
            var $elem=$('.scrollmenu');
            var newScrollLeft = $elem.scrollLeft(),
                width=$elem.width(),
                scrollWidth=$elem.get(0).scrollWidth;
            var offset=8;
            if (scrollWidth- newScrollLeft-width==offset) {
                alert('right end');
            }
            if (newScrollLeft === 0) {
                alert('left end');
            }
           
            
            scrollLeftPrev = newScrollLeft;
         
        });
        
        
   });
```

```css
.container {
    border:0px solid red;
    height:45px;
    overflow:hidden;
width:300px;
 background-color: #333;
}
.scrollmenu {
    width:100%;

    background-color: #333;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
 position:relative;
 display: block;
}
.scrollmenu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  
    background: transparent; 
}
.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
#right,#left{cursor:pointer;pointer-events: all}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td id="left">&#8592;</td>
   <td>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="scrollmenu">
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#news">News</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                    <a href="#support">Support</a>
                    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
                    <a href="#base">Base</a>
                    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
                    <a href="#more">More</a>
                    <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
                    <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
                    <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
                    <a href="#people">People</a>
                    <a href="#work">Work</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="right">&#8594;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5095r3rm/9/

Comment: The `.click()` handlers need to check the position to see if it's reached the end.

Comment: The `.scroll()` event isn't triggered when you use `.animate()`, it only reacts to scrolling by the user when there's a scroll bar.

Comment: Ok I understood....working on it..thnk you

Comment: If you add `.scroll()` after `.animate()`, you'll get the alerts. But your `.scroll()` handler doesn't do anything to undo the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to attach the `scroll` event to your menu, because the event is only fired when the user scrolls manually. You do not need extensive logic to check, because we will rely on a HTML property known as `scrollLeft`. We simply set the parent element to `overflow: auto`, and let the inner `.scrollMenu` expand to its children's total widths.

## Step 1: Small changes to CSS

This is to ensure that all of scrollMenu's children will be visible, and that we support touch devices in the parent container:

```
.container {
  border: 0px solid red;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The key is `display: inline-block`, which will force the menu to expand to the width of its wrapped children.

As you might have notice, desktop browser will have an ugly scrollbar that is visible. You might want to hide the scrollbar on desktop browsers or other non-touch devices ;) a simple way is to do this using JS: `'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement`, and when its true you add a class to your `<html>` or `.container` element. See the proof-of-concept for an implementation.

## Step 2: Perform checks on offset in click handlers

Simply use jQuery's animate to tween the parent's scrollWidth. The browser will not scroll beyond the scrollable area, so you don't need any logic to detect overflows ;)

```
$("#left").click(function(event) {
  var $elem = $('.scrollmenu');
  var $parent = $elem.parent();
  $parent.animate({ scrollLeft: '-=60' }, 300);
});

$("#right").click(function(event) {
  var $elem = $('.scrollmenu');
  var $parent = $elem.parent();
  $parent.animate({ scrollLeft: '+=60' }, 300);
});
```

---

## Proof-of-concept

Here is the proof-of-concept example, with some very rudimentary touch support detection to toggle the scrollbar in the menu's parent element:

```js
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)
  $('html').addClass('has-touch');

$("#left").click(function(event) {
  // Check if menu has reached left edge
  var $elem = $('.scrollmenu');
  var offsetLeft = parseInt($elem.css('left'));
  if (offsetLeft > 0) {
    $elem.css('left', 0);
    return;
  }
  
  // Ensure that we don't overscroll
  var scrollDistance = Math.min(Math.abs(offsetLeft), 60);
  
  event.preventDefault();
  $elem.animate({
    "left": "+=" + scrollDistance + "px"
  }, "slow");
});

$("#right").click(function(event) {
  // Check if menu has reached right edge
  var $elem = $('.scrollmenu');
  var scrollWidth = $elem[0].scrollWidth;
  var parentWidth = $elem.parent().outerWidth();
  var offsetLeft = parseInt($elem.css('left'));
  
  if (offsetLeft <= parentWidth - scrollWidth) {
    $elem.css('left', parentWidth - scrollWidth);
    return;
  }
  
  // Ensure that we don't overscroll
  var difference = Math.abs(parentWidth - scrollWidth) - Math.abs(offsetLeft);
  var scrollDistance = Math.min(Math.abs(difference), 60);
  
  $(".scrollmenu").animate({
    "left": "-=" + scrollDistance + "px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 0px solid red;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Support touch devices */
html.has-touch .container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.scrollmenu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

#right,
#left {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">&#8592;</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="scrollmenu">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#support">Support</a>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
          <a href="#base">Base</a>
          <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
          <a href="#more">More</a>
          <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
          <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
          <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
          <a href="#people">People</a>
          <a href="#work">Work</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id="right">&#8594;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wow,  your answer is just awesome @Terry, something I have no clear is this _...e need to access the full width the menu. Your CSS style does not..._ what if I want to add `overflow:auto` to `.scrollmenu` to add it scroll touch functionality. Adding that the menu would be perfect

Comment: @joe I've had an epiphany and updated my answer ;) it is extra simple now, no crazy logic involved!

Comment: initially the code, `.scrollmenu` was working with `overflow:auto` along with css code to hide the scrollbar, then I started upgrading in Jquery and to make it work it lost this `overflow:auto` functionallity. your ansewer is pretty well elaborate. I appreciatte that..how do I hide this scrollbar in .`contianer` now?

Comment: @joe You’ll have to hide the scroll bar when the device does not support touch. Might want to rely on modernizr to do it, since there is no reliable way in CSS to detect touch event support

Comment: @joe I've updated my answer to include a very rudimentary JS-based detection for touch events.